# Error: Call to a member function find() on a non-object

Tags: php, controller

I am new at php. I have a simple error but cant fix the problem.

> Error: Call to a member function find() on a non-object
>
> File:
>   /var/www/html/cake27/Temploc/Controller/TemperatureReadingsController.php
>
> Line: 59

here is the part of the script in an order and clerified the lines 58,59,60,61:

```
public function edit($id = null) {
    if (!$this->TemperatureReading->exists($id)) {
        throw new NotFoundException(__('Invalid temperature reading'));
    }
    if ($this->request->is(array('post', 'put'))) {
        if ($this->TemperatureReading->save($this->request->data)) {
            $this->Session->setFlash(__('The temperature reading has been saved.'));
            return $this->redirect(array('action' => 'index'));
        } else {
            $this->Session->setFlash(__('The temperature reading could not be saved. Please, try again.'));
        }
    } else {
        $options = array('conditions' => array('TemperatureReading.' .$this->TemperatureReading->primaryKey => $id));
```

$this->request->data = $this->TemperatureReading->find('first', $options);

```
58- }

59- $locations = $this->TemperatureReading->Location->find('list');

60-
        $this->set(compact('locations'));

61- }
```

Comment: Need more code than this. Preferably what you defined 'find' as and some code from TemperatureReadingsController.php

Comment: is just a wild guess, but mby you misspelled: "TemperatureReading" and it should be like "TemperatureReadings".

Comment: I ve checked the spelling but it s correct fsn.

Comment: Maybe you could show more context, particularly regarding the scope of the $this, and if it has a TemperatureReading method you can call?

Comment: Ok i m gonna add more of it @WillCampbell

Comment: I put more content @Martin

Comment: Thanks for not helping :S